# move menu button slightly right

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to have a controller with both back button and menu button as in given image.[amazon app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GekpR.png)

But the problem is the even after increasing the x-axis value it does not shift to right. Hence, I am unable to add back button image. Here's what I am doing right now.

```
button  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 100, 100, 25)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] action:@selector(toggleLeftMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: have you tried using `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`?

Comment: Try autolayouts, also can you show what you are facing right now?

Comment: right now there's only menu icon instead of back icon

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(back)];
UIBarButtonItem *btnMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(menu)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnBack, btnMenu, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well on your code you specifically replaced the back button with a barBarButtonItem.

BTW, your naming is a bit confusing you are assigning a rightBarButtonItem to the leftBarButtonItem of the navigationController.

```
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems= @[leftButton,menuButton]; // this will assign both button on the left side. same thing for rightBarButtonItems
```